# How can I free the pointer in my linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Intro :
The main function is meant to read from a FileDescriptor until it has found the EOF or a line feed. The size of my buffer is define by the user and you can use multiple FileDescriptor since my linked list is static.
My problem :
Depending on the size of the buffer (even or not), I get after the second call (if I don't free, it all works perfectly, but I'd rather not have memory leaks) :
pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
The only free I have is in my building function :

```
int gnl_build(int fd, char *buf, int ret, gnl_lst **head)
{
    gnl_lst *elem;
    char    *str;

    elem = *head;
    while (elem && elem->fd != fd)
        elem = elem->next;
    if (elem == NULL)
    {
        //building new element
        elem = (gnl_lst *)lstnew(buf, (size_t)(ret + 1));
        elem->fd = fd;
        lstaddback((t_list **)head, (t_list *)elem);
    }
    else
    {
        //create new memory space and copies both strings in the new space
        str = strjoin(elem->content, buf);
        free((*elem).content);
        elem->content = str;
        elem->content_size = strlen(str) + 1;
    }
    if (strstr(elem->content, "\n") != NULL)
        return (1);
    return (0);
}
```

Any help is welcome ! Thanks.

Comment: This is all heavily dependent on what `strjoin` does, and what the origin of `elem->content` is. btw, I don't understand why you use `(*elem).content` and not `elem->content`

Comment: Post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We're not mind-readers, and have no clue what the functions you're calling, but not showing, actually do.

Comment: While valid, `(*elem).content` is bad style. Use the arrow operator.

Comment: @MarkNunberg I was actually doing free(elem->content) at first but it wasn't working. Someone gave me this "techniques" and it seemed to be "working"
And I actually feared that it wasn't enough but I didn't want to overflow(see what I did there) with informations. Most functions I use are part of the library in C.

Comment: @MarkNunberg I think that you pin point my problem ! I need to secure the return of strjoin.
strjoin malloc the size of the first + the size of the second string (+ 1, ofc)

Comment: Well, thank you all !
@WhozCraig you actually made me think outside the boxe ! The problem was actually not only in the function that is shown.